# blockingGetAuthToken in AccountManager 3rd parameter

Tags: android

In the documentation, android account manager  `blockingGetAuthToken` states that if its third parameter `notifyAuthFailure` is false, it will prompt the user the login activity and wait for him to neter data. But nothing happens

PS: I traced it to my `getAuthToken` in my authenticator.

is there something that I have missed in the documentation or it's something else ?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use this instead:

```
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> resultFuture = accountManager.getAuthToken(
        account,
        AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE,
        null,
        activity,
        null,
        null
);
Bundle bundle = resultFuture.getResult();
return bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

I guess `blockingGetAuthToken()` is unable to do this automatically because it lacks the `activity` parameter. And the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't pick an answer as correct one because I don't remember what happened back then nor what was the project.. I voted up